# Is it possible to be informed when clipboard content changes outside of java

Tags: java, swing, clipboard

The thing I would want to do is that when the user copies a text in any program (firefox, notepad, pdfReader etc.) my already running java application shall be informed and immediately shows a popup.

I think in order to be able to do this my java application should be invoked whenever system clipboard is changes.

Is that possible with java, if so in which version? I know we can reach and manipulate system clipboard content but my specific question is about invoking the java app. when clipboard content changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would have naively pretended it's a job for JDIC, but the interwebz told me the truth. So, let me explain a little.

using [`Toolkit.getSystemClipboard()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getSystemClipboard()), you can get access to the native system clipboard. Like any Java object, this clipboard can be listened. Precisely, you can call [`Clipboard.addFlavorListener(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html#addFlavorListener(java.awt.datatransfer.FlavorListener)) to listen to [`FlavorEvents`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/FlavorEvent.html). What are they ? [They're the metal kings !](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kings_of_Metal) .... no no no, I completely and utterly digress. Let me come back. So, a FlavorEvent, according to the doc, indicates that

> that available DataFlavors have changed in the Clipboard (the event source).

Which **may** means that Clipboard content has changed. However, I would not go directly on it without a first prototype.

**EDIT** Example of a prototype from the fingers of [AlexR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478399/alexr)

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.FlavorEvent;
import java.awt.datatransfer.FlavorListener;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().addFlavorListener(new FlavorListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void flavorsChanged(FlavorEvent e) { 
                System.out.println("changed!!! " + e.getSource() + " " + e.toString()); 
            } 
        }); 
        Thread.sleep(100000L); 
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, but does this fire if the contents change without the DataFlavors changing, I wonder?

Comment: That's why I say a prototype has to be made :-) It is not a proven solution, only a hint at the simplest possible solution.

Comment: I have just tried this and this really works! Thanks, @Riduidel! Here is my code: public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().addFlavorListener(new FlavorListener() {
   @Override
   public void flavorsChanged(FlavorEvent e) {
    System.out.println("changed!!! " + e.getSource() + " " + e.toString());
   }
  });
  Thread.sleep(100000L);
 }

Comment: @dds I expected it so :-) Thanks to @AlexR for its brilliant example.

Comment: This approach works only when copying from an application once at a time. As Flavor event will not change if copy one more time at the same application. Monitoring by clipboard owner change would be more reliable. Here is the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484927/listen-to-clipboard-changes-check-ownership

Comment: This does not work if new data is copied that has the same flavor.

Comment: I do not understand why this is accepted or received any upvotes, as it does not fire when the flavor did not change.

Comment: As @scravy already mentioned, it does not answer the question.