# How to implement clipboard in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, clipboard

How to make clipboard lister that continuous listen for clipboard change in JavaFX?

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX relies on Java libraries for such functionality.

You can find an example of working with Clipboard from Java here: [listen to clipboard changes, check ownership?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484927/listen-to-clipboard-changes-check-ownership)