# Java - How to setEnabled() on paste Action?

Tags: java, swing, listener, paste, jmenuitem

I am doing my own Notepad in Java. Basic part is almost done. But i have big problem with `JMenuItem` which pastes words to `JTextPane`. It works(pasting), but i want that JMenuItem reacts:

- when is something in memory(copy - from anywhere) => JMenuItem will be `setEnabled(true)`
- when isnt something in memory > JMenuItem will be `setEnabled(false)`

  ```
  private static JMenuItem editPaste; // atribut
  editPaste = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction()); //in private method
  ```

I have no idea, what I should listened(listener of what??) for this action. I did not see that anywhere(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html).

Comment: Do you want to have separate (your custom) memory from the OS defaults? Then - yes, you can implement it and fire events on memory status changes

Comment: @Tala No, I dont want to separate it(I dont know exactly). I want the same funkcionality like in Notepad or Notepad++.

Comment: hmm ... isn't there nearly always something on the clipboard? Anyway, the default textActions have no enablement management at all: you have to implement it yourself. For paste you can try a FlavourListener on the clipboard that enables/disables the action as appropriate.

Comment: some details as to (the missing) enablement management in text actions: https://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-289

Comment: There's a class ClipBoard in java and you can register a FlavourListener on it. May that helps. I've never tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you for advices and keywords. I win, partly :)

For my case works:

```
// atributes
private static JMenuItem editPaste;
private static Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard(); 
// private method
clipboard.addFlavorListener(new ListenerPaste());
editPaste = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction());
editPaste.setEnabled(false);
// listener 
private static class ListenerPaste implements FlavorListener {
    public void flavorsChanged(FlavorEvent e) {
        checkPaste();
    }
}
// private method
private static void checkPaste() {
    try {
        if(clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor) != null) {
            editPaste.setEnabled(true);
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// in constructor we check it also
checkPaste();
```

I do not know, if this is the most appropriate solution, but for me it works. That line which is commented - for real time it doesnt work very well - more: [listen to clipboard changes, check ownership?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484927/listen-to-clipboard-changes-check-ownership)
Next source: 
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-get-a-string-from-the-clipboard.html