Javafx table copy/paste listener
What's the proper way of listening to copy/paste commands on a Javafx table?
I don't want to just listen for Ctrl+C keys because the user may be in a Mac.
Edit: Also, windows 11 now uses both Ctrl+C and Ctrl+INSERT for copying. How can I handle that without checking OS and creating additional key listeners for Windows 11?

This question is a bit broad, and changing/adding behaviors to JavaFX controls is generally not easy, but note that you can query key events for the SHORTCUT modifier which is the semantic modifier represented by CTRL on Windows and META on Mac.

As James said:  listen for Shortcut+C, not Ctrl+C.

Might check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484927/listen-to-clipboard-changes-check-ownership

What is the point of using a JavaFX copy/paste listener?  Sure you could add one, but I don't know what you would do with it.  What do you intend to happen when the listener is fired for both copy and paste functions.  Please edit the question to describe this in detail, preferrable with explanations on how it may work for example data, and information on what range of selection you are expecting for the copy and paste function (whether it spans cells for both copy and paste), whether the table would be in edit mode for paste to work, and if so edit on cells or the entire table, etc.

Consider if this is an XY Problem. Do you actually need to react to the copy/paste actions themselves? Or do you just need to react when the text of a control changes? For the latter, you can listen/subscribe/bind to the appropriate property. Or perhaps if the control is a TextField or similar, then set its onAction property.

For copy/paste with the keyboard, JavaFX supports a semantic "shortcut" modifier, which is equivalent to "control" on Windows and Linux or "Meta" (also called "Command") on Mac. This is described in the documentation for KeyCombination:

The shortcut modifier is used to represent the modifier key which is used commonly in keyboard shortcuts on the host platform. This is for example control on Windows and meta (command key) on Mac. By using shortcut key modifier developers can create platform independent shortcuts. So the "Shortcut+C" key combination is handled internally as "Ctrl+C" on Windows and "Meta+C" on Mac.

You can use this when handling key events using KeyEvent.isShortcutDown() or in accelerators or mnemonics using, e.g. new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.C, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN).

Edit in response to

Edit: Also, windows 11 now uses both Ctrl+C and Ctrl+INSERT for copying. How can I handle that without checking OS and creating additional key listeners for Windows 11?

As far as I am aware there is no general "Is this action a platform COPY action" API in JavaFX. I don't have a Windows machine to test (or, indeed, a Mac keyboard with an "INSERT" key), but I think for the text input controls Shortcut+INSERT is implemented as "copy" and Shift+INSERT is implemented as "paste", on all platforms.
You can see how the text input controls implement keyboard handling here. Essentially, different input mappings are created for each key combination that maps to each handler, and a central event handler uses the mapping to determine the action when a key event occurs. (So there is a separate input mapping for Ctrl+C and Ctrl+INSERT, both mapping to the same action.) Note these behavior classes are not part of the public API, which makes it pretty difficult to modify behaviors in JavaFX.

Thanks. I was aware of shortcut modifier but was hoping there was a better option that does not require hard-coding key combinations. For example, windows 11 now uses both Ctrl+C and Ctrl+INSERT for copying. How would you handle that without checking OS and creating additional key listeners for Windows 11?

@SaeidNourian Added some comments addressing that to the answer

@SaeidNourian If you're putting something like a TextField in a table's cells, then you could probably subclass TextField and override its copy, cut, and paste methods.

Looking into details of how TextField handles copy I noticed it listens to 3 KeyCodes: KeyBinding(C).shortcut() and KeyBinding(INSERT).shortcut() and KeyCode.COPY. At first I was happy to discover KeyCode.COPY since it appeared to be exactly what I was looking for. But unfortunately pressing Ctrl+C did not trigger it. Anybody here knows the function of KeyCode.COPY?

@SaeidNourian Some keyboards have a specific key called “Copy”.

yup, it appears that Java has no generic way to receive copy/paste events.  I have to check all valid key combos for all different OSs manually in my code. I'm accepting this answer.
