# Event of changing clipboard content

Tags: java, scala, clipboard

I have this code to watch for clipboard:

```
import java.awt._
import java.awt.datatransfer.{StringSelection, DataFlavor}

object Application extends App {
  val c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.getSystemClipboard

  val selection = new StringSelection("123theStringaaaaaaa")
  c.setContents(selection, selection)
  println(c.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
}
```

Is there any way to subscribe to an event of changing clipboard (something new is copied to clipboard)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be two approaches. Either add a [FlavorListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/FlavorListener.html), or maintain ownership of the clipboard by implementing the [ClipboardOwner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/ClipboardOwner.html) interface. From reading other questions, neither approach is perfect, and you may have to play around with some code to see what meets your specific requirements.

- [listen to clipboard changes, check ownership?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484927/listen-to-clipboard-changes-check-ownership)
- [calling a method when content of clipboard is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226064/calling-a-method-when-content-of-clipboard-is-changed)
- [Is it possible to be informed when clipboard content changes outside of java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802982/is-it-possible-to-be-informed-when-clipboard-content-changes-outside-of-java)

Comment: But none of them are working well, at least 2 of them load a processor with 100%. And they only catch ctrl+c combination.

Comment: well, how do I catch inserting data to clipboard?