# A class inherited from Thread makes CPU run 100%

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, keyboard

I have such code in my application which I want to run in background:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;

class Main extends Thread implements ClipboardOwner {

    private Clipboard sysClip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

    public void run() {
      Transferable trans = sysClip.getContents(this);
      regainOwnership(trans);
      System.out.println("Listening to board...");
      while (true) { }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Main b = new Main();
      b.start();
    }
  //............
```

It listens for `Ctrl+C` and prints the content of clipboard once this key combination is pressed. However, it makes CPU run 99% all the time. If I remove `while (true) { }` then the application will just stop in a second.

I tried to launch it as `java -jar myapp.jar &` but the result was the same. And it would be the same on  Windows I guess, although I care about Linux for now.

What do I do about that?

Comment: Try to add Thread.sleep(<ms>) inside your while loop.

Comment: dont extend thread. implementing runnable is better

Comment: Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/

Comment: @Alex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a thread running an infinite loop. That's exactly the sort of thing that will use 100% of your CPU for nothing. If nothing else, putting a couple second `Thread.sleep()` in the loop will bring the CPU usage down.

Comment: the maximum amount of time it can sleep is 0.5 sec. Does it make sense to use Thread.sleep?

Comment: @Alex yes.  Half a second is a huge time for a cpu.

Comment: @Alex You should be able to pass any arbitrary long argument to [`Thread.sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)).

Comment: Is it? I thought only starting from a few seconds would be reasonable enough.

Comment: Put Thread.sleep(1) in the loop and notice how it lowers the CPU usage.

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, shouldn't I use runnable instead?

Comment: Well, using Runnable won't change the general execution of the code. It's just a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using eternal loops to check if a variable has changed, but rather use a listener. To be more precise, a [FlavorListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802982/is-it-possible-to-be-informed-when-clipboard-content-changes-outside-of-java) will allow you to execute code when the clipboard has changed.

It would be something like this:

```
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().addFlavorListener(
        new FlavorListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void flavorsChanged(FlavorEvent e) { 
            System.out.println("Clipboard contents: " + e.toString()); 
        } 
    });
```

Comment: I saw this code already and it didn't work. Could you give a full working example?

Comment: I don't, but these guys have some pointers: http://www.coderanch.com/t/377833/java/java/listen-clipboard

Comment: and where is FlavorListener there?